# Doctrine delete by subquery with in same table

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to delete record from mysql using doctrine

Corresponding MYSQL Query

```
DELETE FROM user_fields_data WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT id FROM user_fields_data WHERE id IN (
            SELECT block_id FROM user_fields_data WHERE template = 1
        )
    ) AS `ss`
) AND template = 1
```

Trying to delete using Doctrine:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

$blockId = $qb->select('bl.blockId')
    ->from('UserFieldBundle:UserFieldsData','bl')
    ->where('bl.template = 1');

$ids = $qb->select('bl2.id')
    ->from('UserFieldBundle:UserFieldsData','bl2')
    ->where($qb->expr()->in('bl2.id',$blockId->getDQL()));

$result = $qb->delete('UserFieldBundle:UserFieldsData','USF')
    ->where($qb->expr()->notin('USF.id', $ids->getDQL()))
    ->andWhere('USF.template = :templateId')
    ->setParameter('templateId', 1)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSQL();

dump($result);
```

Doctrine query ends with error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 65: Error: Expected Literal, got 'DELETE'"

Database Structure:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8V8ctsecVBKSNgsCrhuc4/1

Comment: Please, attach the error as well.

Comment: @DonCallisto error message has added

Comment: For something this complex why not just use a raw SQL query?